# Adding a watermark in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, watermark

I`m trying to add a watermark to a image in yii project without using any extension. Now i am in a position where the watermark is adding to the image propoerly but when I try to save the watermarked image into the DB I am getting an error " Call to a member function saveAs() on resource".

The code before adding the watermark

```
//upload profileImageFile
if(UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profileImageFile')){
    $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profileImageFile'); 
    $filename = $file->baseName . '_' . time() . '.' . $file->extension;
    $path = AUTO::PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH;
    $imageModel = new Image();    

                    if($imageModel->upload($file, $path, $filename)){
                        $imageModel->filename = $filename;
                        $imageModel->path = $path . $filename;
                        $imageModel->status = Image::STATUS_ACTIVE;
                        $imageModel->save();
                        $model->profile_image_id = $imageModel->id;
                    }
                }
```

The code after  adding the watermark

```
//upload profileImageFile
                if(UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profileImageFile')){
                    $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profileImageFile'); // get the object
                    $filename = $file->baseName . '_' . time() . '.' . $file->extension;
                    $path = AUTO::PROFILE_IMAGE_PATH;
                    $imageModel = new Image();

                    //add watermark
                    $watermarkImage = imagecreatefrompng('C:/xampp/htdocs/Autobank/frontend/web/images/watermark_image.png');
                    $autoImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($file->tempName);
                    $marge_right = 10;
                    $marge_bottom = 10;
                    $sx = imagesx($watermarkImage);
                    $sy = imagesy($watermarkImage);
                    imagecopy($autoImage, $watermarkImage, imagesx($autoImage) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($autoImage) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImage), imagesy($watermarkImage));


                    if($imageModel->upload($autoImage, $path, $filename)){
                        $imageModel->filename = $filename;
                        $imageModel->path = $path . $filename;
                        $imageModel->status = Image::STATUS_ACTIVE;
                        $imageModel->save();
                        $model->profile_image_id = $imageModel->id;
                    }
                }
```

This is the upload() method in the Image.php model class.

```
public function upload($file, $path, $filename)
{
    $old = umask(0);
    if (!file_exists ($path))
        mkdir ($path, 0755, true);
    umask($old);

    $file->saveAs($path . $filename);
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this and how to save the watermarked image into the DB ?

Comment: As the error says, your `$file` variable is an **resource**, not an **object**. Function `imagecreatefromjpeg()` returns resource. Btw, you could use **already build in out-of-box** solution to add watermark in OOP way [Yii2 BaseImage - watermark()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-imagine-baseimage.html#watermark()-detail)

Comment: the truth has been spoken by @Yupik and there is no reason to add the tag `model-view-controller`